# Buttons inside color frame of kinect

Tags: c#, wpf, kinect

How to bring buttons inside video frame of the kinect app.  I want to bring WPF controls inside colorframe object how to do that..  any idea

The source code provided in the below link is not working..

http://dotnet.dzone.com/news/kinecting-dots-adding-buttons

if you have idea about adding animated list box inside color frame is also appreciated :)

I am working on kinect SDK 1.5

Comment: probably i don`t get your question but can`t you just in xaml editor put button over the video frame element ?

Comment: Please be more specific. No one can understand where you are having trouble you if you don't post any code

Comment: Could it be that this is made of the first beta?

Comment: HI
sorry for not descriptive 
My aim is just want to display controls inside Video Frme element.

E.g:  we are showing the kinect Video inside image control in WPF.

Now I would like to have some WPF controls inside the Video Frame .

I know we can map the X,y co-ordinates and place the controls inside.

but If i Move my hands on the controls nothing happens.

Comment: you have to do the interaction between your hand and the button manually. your hand isn't automatically taking place of your mouse, so it doesn't have any events like the mouse has. So like in the example you posted, you need to have your own hit detection in place. That example is using the skeleton data, but its just not showing all the joints like most examples show. So you need to use the SkeletonStream and based on the x,y position of the Joint and the x,y position of the button you need to determine if the Joint (x,y) in within the bounds of the Button (x,y)

Comment: Of corse nothing happens, if you are actually incorporating the button **into** your image then it is just apart of it. You need to just place the buttton ontop of the image, not actually into it

Comment: I got a chance to look on the kinect paint app in the codeplex , it looks good I will try to incorporate that with my code.

Answer (score 0):

From your comment, it sounds like you are making one dire mistake, you are inserting the button ***into*** the frame, not ***on*** the frame. Then the button is part of the image and not a control on your form, meaning that it is then useless. Hope this helps!